# How to Automate repeated tasks in SAP Logon

Tags: python, java, php, automation, sap-gui

I am given a task to automate few boring tasks that people in office do everyday using SAP Logon 640.

There are like 30-40 transactions that are required to be automated.

I searched a lot on SAP Automation and found SAP GUI Scripting but failed to find any starting point for python, php or java.

How should i start to automate SAP transactions using python , php or java ?  I am not even sure what i need from my IT department to get started.

Comment: what exactly do you need to automate? There are several technologies available, from batch input to the legacy systems migration workbench. Complex scenarios can sometimes be automated by using SAP workflows.

Comment: I have to fetch data by using a transaction code and few input items. currently they use SAP Logon 640 desktop client to read data.

Comment: fetch data and save it somewhere outside the SAP system? That would call for a small desktop application, preferably in java or .net, using the SAP Connector (available for both java and .net) and remote enabled function modules on the SAP server side. You can't call transactions from outside SAP Gui, but you can call function modules like RFC_READ_TABLE and BAPIs like BAPI_MATERIAL_GET_DETAIL. Take a look at the available BAPis using transaction BAPI.

Comment: Did you ever accomplish this task? If so how did you do it?

Answer (score 1):

We use either VBScript or C# to automate tasks. Using VBSCript is the easiest. Have the SAP GUI record a task then it will produce a vbscript that can serve as a starting point for your coding. When you have this vbscript file then you can translate it into other languages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) to automate a lot of tasks in SAP Logon. It can recognise UI elements and interact with them. You just have to provide images of these elements. A lot of functionality in SAP Logon is usable by shortcuts, so you can simulate keyboard input very easily with it either. Sikuli is available for both Java and Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Scheduled Jobs using JAVA if i am understanding you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

SapGui has buit in record and playback tool which gives you out of the box vbs files which you can use for automation , if the values does not change, then you can use the same scripts every time.

You can find it in the main menu of the sap gui window customise local layout(Alt+F12)->Script Recording and playback.

Answer (score 0):

Try Python

I did with this script.

```
    import win32com.client
    import subprocess
    import sys
    import time

    def saplogin():

        try:
            # path to saplogon
            path = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe"
            subprocess.Popen(path)
            time.sleep(10)

            SapGuiAuto = win32com.client.GetObject('SAPGUI')
            if not type(SapGuiAuto) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
                return

            application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
            if not type(application) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
                SapGuiAuto = None
                return
            connection = application.OpenConnection("ModuleName", True)

            if not type(connection) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
                application = None
                SapGuiAuto = None
                return

            session = connection.Children(0)
            if not type(session) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
                connection = None
                application = None
                SapGuiAuto = None
                return

            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").text = "Username"
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").text = "Password"
            session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)
            # **Record Your Script with SAP and paste here**
            print(sys.exc_info())

        finally:
            session = None
            connection = None
            application = None
            SapGuiAuto = None
    saplogin()
```